# How to iterate through this code and make it short?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function computerPlays() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    arr.push(random);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 1) {
            square1.css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                square1.css('opacity', '1')
            }, 500);
        else if (arr[i] === 2) {
            square2.css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                square2.css('opacity', '1')
            }, 500);
        else if (arr[i] === 3) {
            square3.css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                square3.css('opacity', '1')
            }, 500);
        else if (arr[i] === 4) {
            square4.css('opacity', '0.5');
            setTimeout(function() {
                square4.css('opacity', '1')
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

All the if else are similar only the value in test condition and square number changes in every if else how can I avoid this repetition and iterate through this code.

Comment: i think the links explains it pretty clearly , you problem in itself is fine but I can't see any effort you put in trying to solve it yourself and I find that a bit lackluster in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the squares in an array:

```
squareArray = [square1, square2, square3...]
```

Then you can do:

```
squareArray[arr[i] - 1].css('opacity', '0.5');
setTimeout(function() {
    squareArray[arr[i] - 1].css('opacity', '1')
}, 500);
```

using the number to index the right square. Remember to subtract one because arrays are 0-indexed.

**EDIT** Good point made in the comment, if you run into problems with this solution, you might be having issues with closures. It's best then, to first assign the variable and pass it in through a function:

```
var square = squareArray[arr[i] - 1];

square.css('opacity', '0.5');
setTimeout(function(s) { return function() {
    s.css('opacity', '1')
}}(square), 500);
```

Comment: actually not really, because of the closure over `i` it has the value of `arr.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's built-in function for what you are trying to do:

```
var squares = [ square1, square2, square3, square4 ];

function computerPlays()
{
  var i, random;

  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  arr.push(random);

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    squares[arr[i] - 1].fadeTo(0.5)
      .delay(500).fadeTo(1);   // <---- fadeTo() and delay() is what you really want
  }
}
```

> Don't use setTimeout() at all, use pure jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
function computerPlays() {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
    arr.push(random);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        $('#square'+i).css('opacity', '0.5');
        setTimeout(function() {
            square1.css('opacity', '1')
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

You can also could change this thing that repeats for a call from a function this square.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your squares like this:

```
var squares = [0, square1, square2, square3, square4]
```

and then use it within the loop as below:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    squares[ arr[ i ] ].css( 'opacity', '0.5' );
    setTimeout( function (x) {
        return function () {
            squares[ x ].css( 'opacity', '1' )
        }
    }( arr[ i ] ), 500 );
}
```